# directory error migrating Angular Material from 16 to 17

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm trying to run the Angular Material migration tool to migrate from 16 to 17, and am getting an error that directory must be a string.  The JSON shows it to be false.  This is not prompted for, and I am running the command in the project directory.  What am I doing wrong?

```
PS C:\Users\x\portal\client> ng generate @angular/material:mdc-migration
? What components do you want to migrate? Button, Card, Checkbox, Chips, Dialog, Form Field, Input, Select,
Autocomplete, List, Menu, Paginator, Progress Bar, Progress Spinner, Radio, Slide Toggle, Slider, Snack Bar, Table,
Tabs, Tooltip
Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"directory":false,"components":["button","card","checkbox","chips","dialog","form-field","list","menu","paginator","progress-bar","progress-spinner","radio","slide-toggle","slider","snack-bar","table","tabs","tooltip"]}
Errors:

  Data path "/directory" must be string.
```

Answer (score 4):

Workaround until the fix is released:
modify `node_modules\@angular\material\schematics\ng-generate\mdc-migration\schema.json` and remove `"alias": "d",` (as in [this commit](https://github.com/angular/components/commit/6feb26d10701a841f45545d42bd29e873120a131))

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the topic is known and is already fixed, we have to wait for the release with new changes. You can find more information on github issue: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/28335.

Release is already ready. You can use the version "@angular/material: "^17.0.5" and it should work correctly

Comment: Thanks, After the update the command is working, Do you know how to resolve the TODOs left by the migration tool? like ` /* TODO(mdc-migration): The following rule targets internal classes of tabs that may no longer apply for the MDC version. */
  .mat-tab-label-content {
    display: block !important;
  }`